# bypassing naming conventions in cakephp

Tags: hibernate, cakephp, find

1. I already have an existing project with many tables so I can't change their names.
   I want to set up cake php to "hibernate" with the tables- 
   so lets say i have a table called:
   "stock_realtime"
   I have set up a model in Model->"StockRealtime.php":

   class StockRealtime extends AppModel{

   ```
   var $name = 'stock_realtime';
   ```

   }

and the controller is in Controller->"StocksRealtimeController.php"

```
class StocksRealtimeController extends AppController {

    var $name       = 'stock_realtime'; 

    function index() {
        $this->set('stocks', $this->StockRealtime->find('all'));

    }
}
```

and the view in a View->stocks_realtime->index.ctp

I go to the view file and I get an error msg:

```
Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object 
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\s-maof-vb\stocksRT\app\Controller\StocksRealtimeController.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your model, add `var $useTable = 'stock_realtime';`

For your controller add `var $uses = 'StockRealtime';`

Comment: you don't need to set $uses for your controller, though

Comment: @José Lorenzo His controller name is `StocksRealtime`, though. Won't that look for `StocksRealtime' model then?

Comment: The convention is that if you have a model called `StockRealtime`, the controller should be names `StockRealtimesController`. If you want it to be `StocksRealtimeController`, it does not conform to conventions, and therefore needs `$uses`.

Comment: The model connects but now it searches for table 'StockRealtime'.. Error: Table stock_realtimes for model StockRealtime was not found in datasource default.

Comment: Did you add the `useTable` var to the model? If you did, do a debug(get_class($this->StockRealtime)); in your controller, do you get `AppModel` or `StockRealtime`?

Comment: thanks, it works. is there any way that the main view file (app->view->pages->home.ctp) will include this class and not app->view->stocksrealtime->stocks_reatlime.ctp? . I want this to be my main page.